# camel-example-sql-blueprint : Unable to install Kar future

Tags: apache-camel, osgi, apache-karaf, blueprint-osgi

Here is what I did / want to do:

1. added karaf-maven-plugin to pom.xml,
2. ran mvn install.
3. got camel-example-sql-blueprint-2.20.0-SNAPSHOT.kar dropped it in
   /deploy directory [I do not want to execute any command in
   karaf console]

Got this error. How can I create a kar file that has all dependencies? Is there other easier ways of deploying kar file, without going into karaf console.

> 2017-10-05 22:22:30,350 | DEBUG | pool-54-thread-7 |
>   AetherBasedResolver              | 4 - org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn - 2.5.2 |
>   Resolved (org.apache.felix:org.apache.felix.scr.compat:jar:1.0.4) as
>   /Volumes/data/apps/TOS_ESB-20170623_1246-V6.4.1/Runtime_ESBSE/container/system/org/apache/felix/org.apache.felix.scr.compat/1.0.4/org.apache.felix.scr.compat-1.0.4.jar
>   2017-10-05 22:22:30,350 | DEBUG | pool-54-thread-7 |
>   AetherBasedResolver              | 4 - org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn - 2.5.2 |
>   Resolved (org.apache.felix:org.apache.felix.scr.compat:jar:1.0.4) as
>   /Volumes/data/apps/TOS_ESB-20170623_1246-V6.4.1/Runtime_ESBSE/container/system/org/apache/felix/org.apache.felix.scr.compat/1.0.4/org.apache.felix.scr.compat-1.0.4.jar
>   2017-10-05 22:22:31,838 | WARN  | container/deploy | KarServiceImpl
>   | 99 - org.apache.karaf.kar.core - 4.1.1 | **Unable to install Kar**
>   feature camel-example-sql-blueprint/2.20.0.SNAPSHOT
>   org.osgi.service.resolver.ResolutionException: **Unable to resolve root**:
>   missing requirement [root] **osgi.identity**;
>   osgi.identity=camel-example-sql-blueprint; type=karaf.feature;
>   version="[2.20.0.SNAPSHOT,2.20.0.SNAPSHOT]";
>   filter:="(&(osgi.identity=camel-example-sql-blueprint)(type=karaf.feature)(version>=2.20.0.SNAPSHOT)(version<=2.20.0.SNAPSHOT))"
>   [caused by: Unable to resolve
>   camel-example-sql-blueprint/2.20.0.SNAPSHOT: missing requirement
>   [camel-example-sql-blueprint/2.20.0.SNAPSHOT] osgi.identity;
>   osgi.identity=slf4j.api; type=osgi.bundle; version="[1.7.22,1.7.22]";
>   resolution:=mandatory [caused by: Unable to resolve slf4j.api/1.7.22:
>   missing requirement [slf4j.api/1.7.22] osgi.wiring.package;
>   filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=org.slf4j.impl)(version>=1.6.0))"]]
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolutionError.toException(ResolutionError.java:42)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.doResolve(ResolverImpl.java:389)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.resolve(ResolverImpl.java:375)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.resolve(ResolverImpl.java:347)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   org.apache.karaf.features.internal.region.SubsystemResolver.resolve(SubsystemResolver.java:218)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:285)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.doProvision(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:1170)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.lambda$doProvisionInThread$0(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:1069)
>   ~[?:?]    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>   [?:?]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   [?:?]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   [?:?]

Comment: At first glance - I'm guessing you include slf4j-api-1.7.22 JAR in your KAR and it causes problems. Karaf includes slf4j-api by itself (using pax-logging). Please remove slf4j from KAR.

Comment: The example is not intended to be installed as KAR. Install the example as instructed in the readme file.

Comment: Hi @ClausIbsen, Thanks for the response. My intention is to move up -- from what I know in the example, to what I NEED and do not know -- i.e able to deploy in <karafdir>/deploy/MyService.kar (which is close to real-life need).